# Server outside of AWS VPC how to join the AWS simple AD?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc, sssd, amazon-directory-services

I m starting to explore the AWS simple AD services.

I have AWS simple AD setup in my AWS VPC, I have one window and one Ubuntu EC2 instances setup in this VPC as well.

I use this Windows server to create users and groups, and it also works well for my EC2 instance to join the Domain I setup in the Simple AD through `realm and sssd`.

Since when I launch these 2 instances, I can choose `"Domain join directory"` under the Advanced details, so I guess this is one of the reasons why my instances can discover the AD.
Reference Link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/simple_ad_launching_instance.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/directoryservice/latest/admin-guide/simple_ad_join_linux_instance.html

However, I don't know how to let my ubunut server which create outside of AWS to discover the domain I setup on the simple AD.

```
ubuntu@hostname:~# realm discover example.com 
realm: No such realm found: example.com
```

I think first I need to make sure the server outside of AWS should communicate to the VPC where the AD is located.

But I m still not sure what's will be the whole steps to make it works.

Thanks if anyone can provide some thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Did you mean to tag this question with Realm, part of [MongoDB Realm](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/) the database?

Comment: @Jay Hi, Jay. I don't know so much Mongo DB, so not sure if the Realm in MongoDB is the same as this one : https://codymoler.github.io/tutorials/ubuntu-active-directory/

The Realm I mean is used realm to let the Linux server join the active directory domain.

Please let me know if my explanation is unclear enough, I will provide the information if you want more.

Comment: The Realm tagged in the question is a relational database and has nothing to do with Active Directory so I think that's an incorrect tag.

Comment: ok, I removed the tag for the realm, do you have any answer to this question?

Comment: I do not - I support Realm tagged questions only, which is why I saw it.